# Ubuntu falls in emergency mode after upgrade 14.04 -> 16.04

Tags: boot, 16.04, upgrade

I have upgraded my ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04. After loading it falls in emergency mode. Unfortunately I couldn't copy paste output of **journalctl -xb** command (it seems that a journal exists only in emergency mode). So I have written the errors on the piece of paper and copy the errors from one:

```
systemd_udev[294]: specified group 'pugindev' unknown
nvidia-persistentced[564]: Failed to query NVIDIA devices...
syscmd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2dlabel-data.device
Failed to mount /filearchive. Special device /dev/sdc1 does not exists
kernel: hid-generic 0003:046E:6000.0002 usb_submit_urb(ctrl): failed -1
error connecting to ConsoleKit
gnome-session-binary[1019]: error: failed to connect to sys. aborting
```

On NVIDIA: I have a GTX660 series card.

How to solve this ?

Update: 
According to @heynnema's advice, I publish some outputs:

```
hedin@home:~/$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=708e39a6-5e4b-49f8-9ecd-1a52fb6d488f /               ext4       errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=20d00d33-b87d-44e7-954b-c7f9e075a58b none            swap      sw              0       0

# filearchive
/dev/sdc1/ /filearchive ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
/dev/sdb2/ /filearchive2 ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
```

In the following **fdisk -l** output I am cutting **/dev/ram** information:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 119.2 GiB, 128035676160 bytes, 250069680 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x1a3fe5c5

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048 234063871 234061824 111.6G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       234065918 250068991  16003074   7.6G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       234065920 250068991  16003072   7.6G 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xdb2e1f65

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *          2048 1048578047 1048576000  500G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2       1048578048 3292618751 2244040704    1T 83 Linux
/dev/sdb3       3292618752 3907028991  614410240  293G 83 Linux

Disk /dev/sdc: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 7BF3ADEF-908A-4FC0-A9CA-351A1E1096B5

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdc1   2048 3907028991 3907026944  1.8T Microsoft basic data

Disk /dev/mapper/vg0-windows: 50 GiB, 53687091200 bytes, 104857600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/vg0-linux: 40 GiB, 42949672960 bytes, 83886080 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/vg0-tutorial--pv--guest--swap: 128 MiB, 134217728 bytes,    262144 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/vg0-tutorial--pv--guest--disk: 4 GiB, 4294967296 bytes, 8388608 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

And this one about **blkid**:

```
hedin@home:~/$ sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="708e39a6-5e4b-49f8-9ecd-1a52fb6d488f" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="1a3fe5c5-01"
/dev/sda5: UUID="20d00d33-b87d-44e7-954b-c7f9e075a58b" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="1a3fe5c5-05"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="96F41086F4106AAF" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="db2e1f65-01"
/dev/sdb2: LABEL="data" UUID="f7932dfd-a58f-4ae8-8fd3-b0cd3101b69f"   TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="db2e1f65-02"
/dev/sdb3: UUID="u1TVlq-3m3W-F5U3-CsZv-bxDK-gd2t-vbllY7" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTUUID="db2e1f65-03"
/dev/sdc1: LABEL="data" UUID="df5f7814-5511-4bc2-8d59-5b66562575e3" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="7e996145-d0b7-4ac0-bbff-df91eb2c116e"
/dev/mapper/vg0-tutorial--pv--guest--swap: UUID="c892bca6-9dcd-4dc3-a349-9926aefb8290" TYPE="swap"
/dev/mapper/vg0-tutorial--pv--guest--disk: UUID="52b6ebe9-7f7c-48c1-a96e-3173622dacdd" SEC_TYPE="ext2" TYPE="ext3"
```

About my disks in few words: 
1) 128Gb OCZ-VERTEX-4 SSD disk where linux is placed (/dev/sda)

2) 2 TB WD GREEN. /dev/sdc. Have only one ext4 partition. Mounted at /filearchive

3) 2 TB WD GREEN. /dev/sdb. Have three partitions. First one is /dev/sdb1 contains windows. Next one /dev/sdb2 ext4 data partition mounted as /filearchive2. The last is /dev/sdb3 lvm partition.

By the way if I choose on load the following: 
Boot menu -> Advanced mode -> Ubuntu 16.04 (Upstart)

Then I am able to load system. Well using **startx** after ubuntu falls into command line mode. All disks are mounted correctly.

Comment: I assume you have the proprietary Nvidia drivers installed?

Comment: Your problem is that you're trying to mount a disk drive that doesn't exist. Edit your question to include the output of `cat /etc/fstab` and `sudo fdisk -l` (lower case L) and `sudo blkid`, and also tell us about your disk drive configuration. Cheers, Al

Comment: @AndroidDev Yes, the proprietary Nvidia drivers are installed.

Comment: @heynnema Thanks for advice. Updated the post with requested data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of issues...

1. in your /etc/fstab, you're mounting sdc1 as EXT4 when it looks like it **might** be NTFS, or it's possibly corrupted
2. your /etc/fstab mounts your filearchive(s)s by device, instead of UUID. This can cause intermittent mount issues. Change /dev/sdXX to UUID={the value taken from the blkid command}
3. your /etc/fstab mounts filearchive(s) in an unusual place. Normally they should be at /mnt or /media.
4. if sdc1 is NTFS, it **may** have an unclean file system, which could be fixed by a chkdsk in Windows (if you dual-boot and have Windows). You'd also want to disable `fast boot` in the Windows power control panel, and hibernation by `powercfg /h off` in an elevated command prompt window

Short term: I'd just comment out the two filearchive(s) mounts in /etc/fstab so that you can boot now, and fix them after you can boot

Keep us posted.

Comment: Thanks! When I replaced **/dev/sdXX** with **UUID={...}** and restarted the machine ubuntu loaded without issues.